# Joining three tables in Laravel with conflicting column names

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have three tables, here are the relevant columns:

```
events
 id
 name
 location_id
 org_id

locations
 id
 name

orgs
 id
 name
```

Here is the query builder in my controller:

```
$events = DB::table('events')
                ->join ('locations', 'events.location_id', '=', 'locations.id')
                ->join('orgs', 'events.org_id', '=', 'orgs.id')
                ->select('events.id', 'events.name', 'orgs.name', 'locations.name')
                ->get();
    return response()->json($events);
```

And the output is thus:

```
[{"id":"2","name":"HUB 123"}, {"id":"3","name":"HUB Lounge"}]
```

When it should be:

```
 [{"id":"2","name":"Some cool event","org":"Student Senate","location":"HUB 123"}, {"id":"3","name":"Some other cool event","org":"Some club","location":"HUB Lounge"}]
```

It looks like, since all three tables have a 'name' column, the last column to be selected is overwriting the ones before it. Obviously this is not what I want.

Is there a way to give the column a new name in the querybuilder similar to AS in plain MySQL? Will this even solve my issue? Please provide an example with your answer. I'm not a MySQL expert and I'm a beginner at Laravel. I'm only trying to set up a basic API to use with my actual project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alias the columns

```
$events = DB::table('events')
            ->join ('locations', 'events.location_id', '=', 'locations.id')
            ->join('orgs', 'events.org_id', '=', 'orgs.id')
            ->select('events.id', 'events.name as event_name', 'orgs.name as org', 'locations.name as location')
            ->get();
return response()->json($events);
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would something dead simple like this. I have to wait 8 minutes to accept this answer, since you answered so quickly :)

Comment: Even if people always suggest using Eloquent relationships instead of using classic joins, if you find yourself in a situation that you need a sorting functionality with the relationshio fields, then it is your best bet to use this kind of joins up above. Thanks!